# Facebook Send Dialog: Check if a user allows sending him private message

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, message

Before sending private message to Facebook user X, how can I check if this user allows to send him messages ?
Any user can disable the ability of other users (which are not his friends) to send him private messages, by changing the privacy policy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is no longer possible to send messages to users through the Graph API, unless you use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) or want to post directly to the user's wall.

Comment: Maybe it was not clear from my question, but I am using the Send dialog. Before opening the Send dialog I need to check if the target user has not disabled the option to receive private messages from non friends.